# I cant retrieve all rows from a table while web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

this is my code. I actually want to extract all the row from table contacted hosts. but I can only retrieve one row from the table. for loop doesn't work. or maybe I didn't understand it well. I am new to webscraping.

Scraping from: [HYBRID Analysis](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/a1b38a18decb253708e0198bfaaed97ef1c16fc061f1dc8c1ba00e98ef77092e/5ff1a85664a2e10f370a6c02)
with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/a1b38a18decb253708e0198bfaaed97ef1c16fc061f1dc8c1ba00e98ef77092e/5ff1a85664a2e10f370a6c02"
r = requests.session()
page = r.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
id1 = soup.find(id = 'contacted-hosts')
class1 = id1.find_all(class_='table table-striped small')

soup.find('div',{'class':'modal-dialog modal-xl'}).decompose()
soup.find('button',{'class':'btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-labeled smallest'}).decompose()
soup.find('div',{'class':'modal fade bs-example-modal-lg sample-network-traffic-modal'}).decompose()

#print(class1[0].find(class_='warning').get_text())
host1 = [item.find(class_='warning').get_text().strip().replace("\n", "") for item in class1]
print(host1)
```

results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2uLO.png

Comment: I have another output when I run your code. Btw it would have to be a `list` as output why isn't it?

Comment: yes, it would have to be a list. But I try to print out a single line first. then I will change it to a list. but It won't come out properly. I'm new to python. Please help me. @grumpyp

Comment: What's the output of `class1`?

Comment: class1 will print out the whole table. I want to extract it and take only text from it.

Comment: Add the results which it `prints` please